# How to get framework version number which is used in my objective-c iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, version

I have two projects: 
The first is an iOS SDK project which will generate mySDK.framework.
The second is an iOS SDK test project where I import and use mySDK.framework.

Currently mySDK.framework version is 2.0.30, I want to display this SDK version on test project's info page.

How can I get the framework version number I used in my project?

Thanks a lot!